# Why does this JavaScript delete everything after it successfully copies the input value to the element text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When i write my code like bellow, the text in the input field appears in the p element for a second and then it vanishes. And when i remove the form tags the text stays in the p element. Why this happens?

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="txbox" placeholder="enter your name here">
          <button id="btn">click</button>
        </form>
    
        <p id="app"></p>
    
        <script>
          function put() {
            var txt = document.getElementById('txbox').value;
            document.getElementById('app').innerHTML= txt;
          }
    
          var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn');
          mybtn.addEventListener("click", put);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are actually submitting your form when you click on the button. Removing the `<form>` tag means that the button will no longer submit a form, because there is none. That is, of course, often far from the ideal solution. There are two alternative solutions:

1. Use `<button type="button">` so that it does not trigger form submission and reloads the page
2. Use `event.preventDefault` on the click event listener to stop the button submission action from being triggered

Proof-of-concept for solution 1:

```js
function put() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txbox').value;
  document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = txt;
}

var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn');
mybtn.addEventListener("click", put);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txbox" placeholder="enter your name here">
  <button id="btn" type="button">click</button>
</form>

<p id="app"></p>
```

---

Proof-of-concept for solution 2:

```js
function put(event) {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txbox').value;
  document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = txt;
  
  event.preventDefault();
}

var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn');
mybtn.addEventListener("click", put);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txbox" placeholder="enter your name here">
  <button id="btn">click</button>
</form>

<p id="app"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrap your input in a form tag. So, the data will be submitted. If you would like to avoid this behaviour, you need to remove the form tag, and get its content out of it

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txbox" placeholder="enter your name here">
      <button id="btn">click</button>

    <p id="app"></p>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are submiting the form, each time when you click on the button, to prevent the submitting add this.

```
function put(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault(); // to prevent submit of the form
    var txt = document.getElementById('txbox').value;
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML= txt;
  }

  var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn');
  mybtn.addEventListener("click", put);
```